# Select xml data using query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help in querying the data from xml,

Here is xml and query I was using

[image]
I am able return all the values except PhonetypeCode value which is "19", I am not sure that I doing right or not.
Any Help Please

Answer (score 0):

```
select xmldata.p.value('./PhoneTypeCode[1]/@tc', 'int') as [PhoneTypeCode]
from @XML.nodes('/Phone') xmldata(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way -

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
SET @XML = CAST('<Phone>
                   <PhoneTypeCode tc="19"/>
                   <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                   <AreaCode>217</AreaCode>
                   <DialNumber>8332046</DialNumber>
                 </Phone>' AS XML);
SELECT p.value('(.//@tc)[1]','int') AS PhoneTypeCode,
       p.value('data(CountryCode[1])','varchar(50)') AS CountryCode,
       p.value('data(AreaCode[1])','int') AS AreaCode,
       p.value('data(DialNumber[1])','int') AS DialNumber
FROM @XML.nodes('/Phone') xmlData(p);
```